# How can I make a self-relationship in a auth_user table from Web2Py?

Tags: python, web, web2py

In db.py model I try

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
  Field('sexo'),
  Field('rg', unique=True),
  Field('cpf', unique=True),
  Field('rua'),
  Field('numero_casa'),
  Field('bairro'),
  Field('cidade'),
  Field('estado'),
  Field('cep'),
  Field('telefone'),
  # Is here \/
  Field('indicador', db.auth_user)
]
```

I need make a reference in auth_user extras filds for itself. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make self references using an alternative syntax:

```
Field('indicador', 'reference auth_user')
```